# GPS parser function doesn't work with new receiver

Tags: c, parsing, gps

I'm using an old device (2006 - extremely trimmed embedded Linux) to get GPS latitude and longitude from an external receiver. GPS coordinates are displayed on device's LCD display. It used to work fine until the original GPS receiver failed. They replaced it with a new receiver but now it doesn't work anymore, all I see on LCD is: Latitude: - / Longitude: -.

I tried to see if the new GPS receiver is operational. And it seems the GPGGA packets are there. The old device expects GPGGA packets for parsing/processing.

```cpp
char GPSLatBuf[12], GPSLonBuf[12];

int parseGPSData(char * gpsBuffer)
{
  char * p;
  char gpsQuality = '0';

  if((p = strstr(gpsBuffer, "$GPGGA")) == NULL)
     return -1;

  memset(GPSLatBuf, 0, sizeof(GPSLatBuf));
  memset(GPSLonBuf, 0, sizeof(GPSLonBuf));

  p += 7; // UTC time
  if(*p != ',') 
  {
     p += 10; // Latitude
     if(*p != ',') 
     {
        memcpy(&GPSLatBuf[1], p, 9);
        p += 10; // N/S Hemisphere
        if(*p != ',') 
        {
           GPSLatBuf[0] = (*p == 'N') ? '+' : '-';
           p += 2; // Longitude
           if(*p != ',') 
           {
              memcpy(&GPSLonBuf[1], p, 10);
              p += 11; // E/W Hemisphere
              if(*p != ',') 
              {
                 GPSLonBuf[0] = (*p == 'E') ? '+' : '-';
                 p += 2; // GPS quality
                 if(*p != ',')
                    gpsQuality = *p;
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
  if(gpsQuality == '0')
     return -1;

  return 0;
}
```

Expected to see non-void fields like before: +4916.4600 / -12311.1200 (just an example as I see nothing on display right now).

Comment: This is impossible to answer with the available information.  You’ll need to know what the interface to the old receiver was, and how the new receiver behaves differently.  Since you’ve not identified the new model, there’s nothing we can do to help.  Even if you did specify it, there’d be a lot of questions to be answered.  Have you obtained the programming manuals for the new device?  If not, do so.

Comment: Figure out which string is not parsable, generate a test case based on it and debug.

Comment: I thought about debug too, but it's an old device and it provides no debug info, no logs. Luckily we have the source code.

Comment: The code seem to be portable enough to be debugged even not on the target.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: But afaik, GPGGA should be standard NMEA message, right? Or are there variations, different implementations allowed?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Yes indeed, good point...! I could use a laptop maybe... as the device is installed on a vehicle :(

Comment: You're outside my realm of knowledge with "GPGGA" and "NMEA". Yes, it is likely that there are standards. Discussions of standards usually end with a plurality of standards, no two exactly alike. I don't know how the standards have evolved between 2006 and 2019 — or even whether they have evolved since then. And I've still no clue as to what your new GPS receiver sends, or how its connected to your system, or how you verify that it is connected and working, etc. Good luck — but there's a lot of information that'll be needed to resolve this, I think. I've indicated I'm not a GPS domain expert.

Comment: The Gps receiver sends the GPGGA messages via UDP broadcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is not too late.
The idea is: the number of decimal digits of data inside GPGGA message<sup>*</sup> is somehow specific to GPS module.
Hence, your code has an issue here, as it uses fixed offsets to search for latitude, longitude, etc.
It is easy to fix that: instead of using fixed offsets, you should search for the delimiter ("," in this case) using `strstr()` function.
Here's the corrected code:

```c
int parseGPSData(char * gpsBuffer)
{
  char * p;
  char gpsQuality = '0';

  if((p = strstr(gpsBuffer, "$GPGGA")) == NULL)
     return -1;

  memset(GPSLatBuf, 0, sizeof(GPSLatBuf));
  memset(GPSLonBuf, 0, sizeof(GPSLonBuf));

  if((p = strstr(p, ",")) != NULL)
  {
      p++; // there is UTC time
      if((p = strstr(p, ",")) != NULL)
      {
          p++; // Latitude
          memcpy(&GPSLatBuf[1], p, 9);
          if((p = strstr(p, ",")) != NULL)
          {
              p++; // N/S Hemisphere
              GPSLatBuf[0] = (*p == 'N') ? '+' : '-';
              if((p = strstr(p, ",")) != NULL)
              {
                  p++; // Longitude
                  memcpy(&GPSLonBuf[1], p, 10);
                  if((p = strstr(p, ",")) != NULL)
                  {
                      p++; // E/W Hemisphere
                      GPSLonBuf[0] = (*p == 'E') ? '+' : '-';
                      if((p = strstr(p, ",")) != NULL)
                          gpsQuality = p[1];
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }

  if(gpsQuality == '0')
     return -1;

  return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this will solve your issue :)

---

**<sup>*</sup>EDIT**:
Here's how NMEA GGA message looks like - an example:

```
$GPGGA,123519,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,1,08,0.9,545.4,M,46.9,M,,*47

where:  
##     GGA          Global Positioning System Fix Data  
##     123519       Fix taken at 12:35:19 UTC  
##     4807.038,N   Latitude 48 deg 07.038' N  
##     01131.000,E  Longitude 11 deg 31.000' E  
##     ...
```

More useful information you can find here: https://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#GGA